# Check if the method of finding density function is correct

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Start by finding the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $Y$:

\begin{align*}
F_Y(y) &= P(Y \leq y) \\
&= P(\ln X \leq y) \\
&= P(X \leq e^y) \\
&= 1 - e^{-\alpha e^y}, \qquad \text{for } y < \infty
\end{align*}

where we have used the fact that the exponential distribution has the probability density function $f_X(x) = \alpha e^{-\alpha x}$ for $x \geq 0$.

To find the density of $Y$, we take the derivative of the CDF with respect to $y$:

\begin{align*}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{d}{dy} F_Y(y) \\
&= \frac{d}{dy} [1 - e^{-\alpha e^y}] \\
&= \alpha e^y e^{-\alpha e^y} \\
&= \alpha e^{-\alpha e^{-y}}, \qquad \text{for } y < \infty
\end{align*}

Therefore, the density of $Y$ is:

$$
f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
\alpha e^{-\alpha e^{-y}} & y < \infty \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: It looks ok, but $\alpha e^y e^{-\alpha e^y} \neq\alpha e^{-\alpha e^{-y}}$.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, thank you for your time

Comment: You're welcome. As far I can see there is no otherwise case. I would say that $f_Y(y)=ae^ye^{-\alpha e^{-y}}, \ \ -\infty<y<\infty$